# SVG to geo coordinates from PHP regex pattern to C# pattern

Tags: c#, php, regex, svg

I want to try the SVG to geo converter from:

http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/02/11/from-svg-to-geo-coordinates-a-complete-guide/

The issue is that I am not used with PHP regular expressions:

```
preg_match('/(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?/', $s, $m);
```

I would like to convert it to C# like:

```
public void Convert(string path)
    {
        if (path == null)
            path = defaultpath.Replace("\r\n","");

        var matches = path.Split('c');

        var pattern= @"/(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?/";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            var result = r.Match(match); //always empty
        }

         //...
    }
```

But no idea what I have to modify in the pattern to make it work?

Thanks, I will post an example with some conversions from Inkscape as soon I be able to use this snippet.

**UPDATE**
After removing the slashes the result is always empty, here is part of the match array:

"-0.86-0.27-3.816,0.199-4.002-1.055"
"-0.049-0.328-1.109-1.799-1.512-1.824"
"-0.647-0.04-5.182,1.896-5.219,2.013"
"-0.051,0.161,0.928,0.627,0.319,0.832"
"-0.028-0.003-0.716-0.36-0.816-0.334"
"-0.13,0.034-0.262,0.834-0.363,0.771"
"-0.176-0.24-0.179-0.48-0.007-0.719"
"-0.986-0.764-0.345,0.764-0.526,0.764"
"-0.771,0,0.184-0.849-0.675,0.037"
"-2.13-0.433-2.267-0.756-4.129-2.754"
"-1.329-1.42,0.383-8.158-1.571-8.535"
"-2.223-3.153-6.413-3.037-8.806-5.037"

Comment: As easy as removing the delimiters: `var pattern= @"(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?(-?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,3}),?";`. .NET regex does not use regex delimiters. Also, you do not need `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` (a digit, comma and hyphen have no case).

Comment: So why after doing that, that I thought was just the issue there is no match with the post example svg data?

Comment: Post the `matches` value.

Comment: posted the some matches values, sorry for the delay

Comment: [I cannot repro, I get a lot of matches](https://ideone.com/WF9k2n).